# Visual Studio Extension no longer opening experimental instance of VS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix

I have a VS extension I've been working on that was working fine. When I run it in VS it would open the experimental instance of VS and load just fine. However, between checking it into TFS, some NuGet references got all messed up and in the process of trying to fix that (it now builds), it's now stopped debugging in the VS experimental instance. Hitting F5 just gives me the complaint about

> A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started

Does anybody know how to fix this? What in the project or solution settings tells it to start debugging in Visual Studio?

I tried comparing `.vsproj` files from a completely clean VSIX project, but I'm not seeing it

Comment: Most obvious mishap is that you lost the Project > Properties > Debug tab settings.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks Hans. I just noticed that about 2 minutes after posting. I was looking for a more complicated solution instead of looking at the obvious thing first. I've no idea how they got lost in the first place, but there you have it.

Comment: There is an extension which let's you reset your experimental instance with 2 clicks, super useful when making a VSIX project. link : [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BenDeveloper.ResetExperimentalInstance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok - never mind, I found it.

Under the project properties on the `Debug` tab, you need to set `Start external program` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` (for example)

And then under `Start Options` you need to add `/rootsuffix Exp` to the `Command line arguments`

I'm not sure how these got lost in the first place, but in case anybody else encounters the same problem.

Comment: They are stored in the .user file, but you can add them permanently to the csproj file: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/SqlCe35Toolbox/VSToolbox.csproj#L10

Comment: @ErikEJ - ah, that would explain it. I probably lost the `.user` file since I was pulling it back from TFS in to a different folder because my nuget references had got messed up.